# How to get the Clear (Cross) icon on a lightning input type search by default without typing anything on it?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-experience

I need a lightning input type search where the clear icon is shown by default. Issue is currently as per documentation only typing something on it, the clear(Cross icon) icon shows. I want as soon as it comes on screen it should show with the clear icon, so that the user doesnt have to type to clear it. Is it possible?

```
 <lightning-input
            name="enter-search"
            label="Search when user hits the 'enter' key"
            type="search"
        ></lightning-input>
```

I dont know how I can achieve this. It cannot be through an onchange event as the element provides this automatically when we type. I need the clear icon by default in the element

Comment: could you clarify what the clear is meant to available for in this scenario? If there is no value in the search, then what would the clear be used for?